# A more efficent way to check if an array in scala resembles to a range

Tags: arrays, scala, range

In order to check if an array contains a range of consecutive elements such as from 1 to 4
I'm using this approach to check if it is true.
But I suppose there is a more efficient way (in terms of time complexity and space) to do it

`(Range(1, a.length).toArray).diff(a).isEmpty)`

How can that be achieved ?

Comment: You can write a simple loop or a tail-recursive function to iterate the array or list _(I would recommend list, or arrayseq)_ to see if each element is equals to the previous plus one. If not, you can stop early.

Comment: Your code, as posted, is not correct. For an `Array(9,1)` it returns **true**, which is, I think, not what you want.

Comment: Please clarify: Does the range have to start at `1`? Is `Array(2,3,4)` valid? Is order significant? Is `Array(1,3,2)` valid?

Comment: Let me explain the case, The check on the array  would return true if no element is missing, which means Array(1,2,3) is valid as well as for Array (7,8,9)  @jwvh

Comment: yes  both examples would return true

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple `O(n)` solution:

```
array.sliding(2).forall{ case Array(a, b) => b == a + 1 }
```

Note that this will fail if there is only 1 element, so that would need to be checked for if it is a possibility.

This has the advantage that it doesn't index into the `Array` so this approach is applicable to other collections such as `List`. It also stops when the first check fails rather than continuing to check other elements.

This is also `O(1)` in memory as `sliding` is lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `indices` and iterate over them like following

```scala
val isRange = array.indices.foldLeft(true) {
  case (soFar, i) => soFar & i + 1 == array(i)
}
```

Memory and time are both `O(n)`.

Comment: Memory is `O(1)` not `O(n)` (which is a good thing!)

Comment: @Tim O(n) is for the array allocation, for the iteration is indeed O(1)

Comment: it iterates the full array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another fast solution which stops when first check fails.

```
  val array= Array(3,5,7,9,10)
  val start_value = 3 // Start value of the array
  val gap_value = 2 //allowed gap between two array elements
  val isRange = !array.indices.exists(i => start_value + gap_value*i != array(i))
```